# iis 7.0 - only local PCs can view the web site despite using port:80?

Tags: http, iis-7, port

First let me explain the steps I did from the very beginning till the end (also to help others):

1- I requested a static IP from my ISP.

2- Inserted that static ip to the **A Record** of mydomain.com

3- I installed IIS and Web Deploy 3.0

4- I setup new web site in the IIS Manager with IP address as my **IPv4** address and port **80** and reconfigured .NET Framework version to 4.0 from the **"Application Pools"** tab in IIS Manager.

5- I added new Windows Firewall **Inbound** Rule as **Predefined** and chose **World Wide Web Services(Http)**

6- I added a simple **index.html** file to the root folder of my domain as testing purposes. ( To help others: With these steps I also accomplished publishing my webApplication with Visual Studio 2012 successfully but for now I'm testing with index.html file which consists just **"Hello World"** )

7- In my router settings; I reconfigured **"Port Forwarding"** as -> **Local IP: 192.168.0.12** (IPv4 addr) & **Start Port:80** & **End Port:80** & **Protocol:TCP**

Now here is my detailed problem:

- When I enter mydomain.com: It shows **"Site Under Construction"** Page. (which shows my domain sellers information)
- When a PC in my LAN enters mydomain.com: it shows **"Hello World"**, no problem here.
- When anybody else enters mydomain.com: They told me that they see **"IIS7 Welcome Page"**

I think one more step will solve both 1st and 3rd problem, however I got stuck despite every investigation I have made.

I'll be very glad if you give any solutions about the problem, Thank You

Murat

Comment: Can you access the IIS7 Welcome Page from outside the LAN using the static IP?  If you can, then I would do an `nslookup` on your domain name to make sure that IP address is what's being pointed to by the DNS servers.  If you can't access the web server via the static IP then there is a configuration issue somewhere else.

Comment: Hello Pete, I asked my friend to browse my static ip with(and)without **":80"** at the end, it worked. However he says it also opened "IIS Welcome Page". It is obvious that external users can connect to IIS. However there is some problem that IIS does not direct the domain to my root folder.

Comment: @Pete , I did nslookup now, and I both tried DNS name server "localhost" and the nameserver which my domain seller provided free. Both returns my external IP address correctly. Only change is in the "DNS Server's address" . Mine is shown as `127.0.0.1#53`. Can you see any problem here?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about IIS specific issues, since I use the apache web server or the like as most others do. But I'd say that you might experience that the address resolution has not yet fully been propagated throughout the internet. This takes a little while, 1-2 days maybe.

The last effect, the "Welcome Page" might be a caching issue. Aks them to make a "deep reload", typically "CTRL-R". But I cannot see any difference in how the page is called compared to the first case.

Comment: To make sure about that's not caching issue, I wanted them to clear their history first, before entering mysite. I searched all over the net but couldnt find any similar problem like this..

Comment: Well there might also be other caches inbetween, like proxies and the like. You can never really deny that possibility.

Comment: What you certainly should do is monitor the web servers logs. You should see the requests whilst they come in. This is usually the first thing to do when something does not work as expected. Also a network sniffer might be of value to monitor how the packages move through your internal network.